# cannot connect to Windows phone 7 device "Access denied"

Tags: windows-phone-7

Has anyone try to debug their app to wp7 device througn vs2010pro?
The phone is registered.. I already reinstall my vs2010pro and windows developer tool, but still the error persists. Windows 7 Ent 64bit.

Comment: At what point are you seeing Access Denied?  Can you provide more details?

Comment: whenever I run the application through wp7 device. my application run smoothly on my emulator.

Comment: @jeffamaphone i already change the usb port, cable etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some points to check (to summarize):

- Device should be dev-unlocked
- Device should have the screen unlocked at the time of debugging
- Device should not have apps installed over the limit (applied to VS-installed apps)
- Zune should be in **full-sync relationship** with the device (not guest)
- If Zune is not running, you need to run the [WP Connect Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg180729%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

If the problem persists, try restarting the device and connecting it again.

Also, is the phone **officially** registered?

Comment: Here's the weird thing.. On other machine, with same dev environment, I can run and deploy on device successfuly.

Comment: On what machine did you register the device?

Comment: I register the device on my machine, but I still can't deploy. I just use my colleague machine to deploy the app.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to deploy your project to the device? (assuming only live debugging is failing)

I have faced this problem at work, and when I de-register the device, and register again, it usually works for me.

Comment: i've used the xap deployment tool, but still access denied.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that the device is definelty reported as unlocked in the app hub.

Check that the device is on, connected, Zune is running and you hav unlocked the device since connecting to Zune.